# Adding a class to a child element in Jquery

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to assign a class to spans that match their parent's id but alas, it's not working.  My failing jQuery looks like this:

```
$("span.genre").click(function(e){
    var genre_id = $(this).attr('id');
    $('span.hidden '+genre_id).addClass('sub_genre');
});
```

and the raw html:

```
<div id="genres">
    <span class='genre' id='1'>Rock</span>
       <span class='hidden 1'>Alternative rock</span>
       <span class='hidden 1'>Art rock</span>
       <span class='hidden 1'>Christian rock</span>
       <span class='hidden 1'>Experimental rock</span>
    <span class='genre' id='5'>R&B/soul</span>
       <span class='hidden 5'>Contemporary R&B</span>
       <span class='hidden 5'>Disco</span>
       <span class='hidden 5'>Soul</span>
       <span class='hidden 5'>Pop R&B</span>
```

Comment: `spans that match their parent's id`: they aren't parents

Comment: Ya you're right.  My bad.  I'm a novice.

Answer (score 0):

You have wrong selector to target span elements.use:

```
$("span.genre").click(function(e){
  var genre_id = $(this).attr('id');
  $('span.hidden.'+genre_id).addClass('sub_genre');
});
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/kcup4mrL/)**

Answer (score 0):

You're just missing a trailing period here `span.hidden.`:

```
$("span.genre").click(function(e){
    var genre_id = $(this).attr('id');
    $('span.hidden.'+genre_id).addClass('sub_genre');
});
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/7gs3mczp/1/)**

What you had, was looking for span elements with the hidden class, and descendant element of 1 or 5 (which wouldn't exist).

Answer (score 0):

Just a little mistake. Youre control got both class so you need to chain it in the selector :

```
$('span.hidden.'+genre_id).addClass('sub_genre');
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do that like this too:

```
$("span.genre").click(function(e){
    $(this).nextUntil('.genre').addClass('sub_genre');
});
```